# Grid items get stuck when using Bootstrap 3 and Isotope masonry layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-isotope

I'm just trying to implement Bootstrap 3 with Isotope and I'm having this problem that when resizing the browser from small to large, at exactly 1200px wide resolution the grid items get stuck and get overlap each other:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ7iR.jpg

At one pixel less width the items (@1199px) look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ1ca.jpg

I've searched everywhere, but many people seem to have a similar problem but not exactly this.

Also here is a bit of html:

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 item metal transition">
        <a href="portfolio-item.html"><img class="img-responsive -img-bot-margin" src="img/img1.jpg"></a>
    </div>

    ...

</div>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
  $(function(){

    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){  
      $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.item'
      });
    });

  });
```

The problem is the same whether I put the columns in rows or not. Also here I'm waiting for the images to get loaded before firing up the isotope. Again the problem is the same if I do not do it this way.

Please let me know if u can tell what is wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: itemSelector : '.item',
        resizable: true, 
        resizesContainer: true

Comment: Make that #container also a class "container" and try adding the above comment.

Comment: Hey, Thanks so much for your reply. So I had .container wrapped around the #container before, and adding .container to #container fixes the problem of the items overlapping each other but it causes a new problem of having 2 columns instead of 3. Can you tell what's wrong?

Comment: Did you put the resize on the Isotope function? I think that it doesn't naturally resize unless you hard reload, that's with Masononry since it has to get width and height on load then since you don't really load when you resize you have to stick the resizeable: true, resizeContainer: true on there.

Comment: And you might need a row around all of it too.

Comment: Yeaah I did that too, I put both of those values there but still it didn't work. Also when the items are overlapped and I refresh the browser they get arranged correctly, it is only when I'm resizing the brwoser that this happens.

Comment: My last comment was the reply to you second last comment. But yeah, I did try putting a row right after the container and around all the comments, but still it is the same. I should also say that this problem is only there in the masonry layout as I also tried with the 'ftiRows' layout and it works fine.

Comment: Well this works, see what you can do with this. I grabbed code from my reliable Isotope configuration and it works with BS3 columns. http://jsbin.com/AkawEtE/1/

Comment: I forgot it needs to add to 12, so add couple more md-3 columns there.

Comment: This one can have any container and is cleaned up. http://jsbin.com/AkawEtE/3/

Comment: @cab Quite a late reply but I just want to say thank you for your help, I tried your code and it worked. It seems like your smartresize function did the trick.

Again thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="container">

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 item metal transition">
    <a href="portfolio-item.html"><img class="img-responsive -img-bot-margin" src="img/img1.jpg"></a>
</div>

...
```

```
$(function() {

  var $container = $('#container');

   $container.imagesLoaded().done(function(instance) {

     $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item'
      });

    });

});
```

It's work for me :)